# Missing number in \chapter declaration?

Tags: errors, chapters

This MWE may be *too* M, but I kept reducing and reducing and this still produces the errors I'm getting and only the errors I'm getting.

This code compiles, but throws two "missing number, treated as zero" errors in the penultimate line.

What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[]{book}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{}}

\chapter[Title]{I}              

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing?

The commands `\Roman`, `\roman`, `\alph`, `\Alph`, and `\arabic` take one argument -- the name of a *counter* variable.

Since it look like you're trying to change the appearance of `chapter`-level entries, it's the `chapter` counter variable you need to change. In short, do replace

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{}}
```

with

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
```

---

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\begin{document}
\chapter[Title]{I}              
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much!